# Django: template loading slowly even using data from cache

Tags: django, caching, django-templates

I have a django app hosted on heroku, and I have a 'family album' page that loads a bunch of image thumbnails which link to a larger image detail page. (And the set of pictures can be different per user).

Each of these thumbnails uses an image_link.html template. At the most there can be up to ~1100 of these thumbnails on the family album page, and it loads peachy in production.

The problem: now I've added a little hover overlay (grabbed from w3schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp)), so that when you mouse over a thumbnail you can see an overlay of who the picture contains. This list of is returned by a method on the Image class- it's not an attribute, so it's not returned with the Image objects.

Adding this has made the template really slow to load: 4-5 seconds locally, and ~22 seconds in production (Heroku, using 1 professional Dyno). I think usually this sort of thing would be made better by pagination, but in this case I like having one long page. (Though I'd be fine with having the top part load first and then the rest fill in afterward).

So I've done a few things:

- added a 'get_image_index_data' function in views.py to loop through, get the pictured_list results, make an array with what I'll need, and cache it. I'm calling this in a receiver function (listening for signal that user logged in) so it'll be set by the time the user clicks the Family Album link, and views.py gets it from the cache
- I added template fragment caching on the family album page

**Issues: even with the data cached (and I confirmed that there wasn't a miss), this can still be slow-loading (until the template fragment caching kicks in? investigating...)**

Here's the code:

I have a receiver function that calls this code to save the data:

```
def get_image_index_data(accessible_branches, profile):
    image_list = Image.objects.none()
    for branch in accessible_branches:
        name = branch.display_name
        image_list = image_list.union(Image.objects.filter(branches__display_name__contains=name).order_by('year'))
    sorted_list = image_list.order_by('year')

    # Save time on Family album page (aka image_index) by calling ahead for pictured_list. Elsewhere the template will retrieve it
    family_album_data = []

    for image in sorted_list:
        family_album_data.append([image, image.pictured_list])

    image_cache_name = 'images_' + str(profile.user)
    cache.set(image_cache_name, family_album_data, 60 * 30)  # save this for 30 minutes
    return family_album_data
```

Then here's the function to render the family album:

```
@login_required(login_url=login_url)
def image_index(request):
    profile = get_display_profile(request).first()
    accessible_branches = get_valid_branches(request)

    image_cache_name = 'images_' + str(profile.user)
    family_album_data = cache.get(image_cache_name)
    if not family_album_data:
        family_album_data = get_image_index_data(accessible_branches, profile)

    context = {'image_list': family_album_data, 'accessible_branches': accessible_branches, 'branch2_name': branch2_name,
                'profile': profile, 'user_person': profile.person, 'media_server': media_server, 'user': profile.user}
    return render(request, 'familytree/image_index.html', context)
```

And here's the family album template (image_index.html):

```
{% extends 'familytree/base.html' %}
{% block title %} - family album{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
{% load cache %}

{% cache 1800 album profile %}

<h1>Family Album</h1>
{% if image_list %}
    {% for image in image_list %}
        {% include "familytree/image_link.html" with image=image height=150 show_hover=True pictured_list=pictured_list%}
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>No images are available.</p>
{% endif %}


{% endcache %}
{% endblock content %}
```

image_link.html (the new bit is the overlay span in the 'if show_hover' block):

```
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom:10px"; class="image_container">
    <a href="{% url 'image_detail' image.id  %}">
        {%  if image.little_name %}
            <img src="{{ media_server }}/image/upload/h_{{ height }},r_20/{{ image.little_name }}" class="image"/>
        {%  else %}
            <img src="{{ media_server }}/image/upload/h_{{ height }},r_20/{{ image.big_name }}" class="image"/>
        {%  endif %}

        {% if show_hover %}
            <span class="overlay">
                <span class="text">Pictured: {{pictured_list}}</span>
            </span>
        {%  endif %}

        <div style="padding-left: 8px">
        {%  if image.year %}
            ({{ image.year }})
        {%  endif %}
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you use task queues like celery? You can probably delegate the cache building there so your requests aren't interrupted

Comment: `but in this case I like having one long page` -- you can also have a look at doing a facebook-like infinite scroll pagination, to give the illusion that you have a long page but still paginating in the background

Comment: thank you! I moved the cache building into a receiver function after the user logs in, and this makes the homepage faster again (phew). The infinite scroll pagination is a good idea- I'll look that up!

Comment: Thanks, bdbd! I'm added infinite scroll with Waypoints- feel free to turn into an answer and I'll give it a checkmark for stackoverflow points :)
http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/

Comment: Sure thing! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. Delegate the cache building on a background process handler like `celery`
2. If you want to display a long page, have a look at doing a facebook-like infinite scroll pagination, to give the illusion that you have a long page but still paginating in the background.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I moved the cache building into a receiver function after the user logs in, and this makes the homepage faster again. Then I added infinite scroll with Waypoints using a combination of their 'getting started' steps and a tutorial. Now everything's loading quickly! \o/